# .htaccess for either redirecting to subdomain or applying certain rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am hosting a zend framework project on a subdomain. Lets say, `project.mydomain.com`. This domain however can be accessed from `mydomain.com/project` as well. Now, to avoid the complexity of having to maintain two different cases, I am trying  to minimize the complexity by redirecting the directly accessed path to the subdomain, i.e.

> mydomain.com/project > project.mydomain.com

but, if the same direcoty is accessed using subdomain, then i want some rules to be applied to it as well.

Here is my currect .htaccess which is allowing me to use direct path i.e mydomain.com/project/

```
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude some directories from URI rewriting
#RewriteRule ^(dir1|dir2|dir3) - [L]

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /projects/myproject.com/public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/myproject.com/public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /projects/myproject.com/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Next, I will write a .htaccess for subdomain only. But, I  want the directly accessed path to be redirected to the subdomain. How to do this redirection through .htaccess?

Please note, redirecting through a php file is not a option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin, it looks like you are trying to redirect the path `mydomain.com/projects` to `projects.mydomain.com`. So, I dont think this is going to be combined .htaccess. As you would need, pretty much everything from `/projects/your-anotherproject` to has to be redirected to `projects.mydomain.com/your-anotherproject`. Rewriting htaccess for every projects is a BAD idea.

**If this is the case**, then i suggest having a simple .htaccess on `projects/` root instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/projects/(.*)$ http://projects.mydomain.com/$1
```

This will solve you all cases, for all subdirectory, on that subdomain. Now write your project specific `.htaccess` in the project's root, like you are doing above